# Passing multiple values into a python function

Tags: python-3.x

How do you pass multiple values into a function?

I'm needing a function which allows the user to enter multiple values. When I call the function I want it to be able to handle an endless list of values like this:
`search_columns_multi_val(column_name, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...`)

So, the list of numbers stored in the values parameter should come in as a list of values.

This is as far as I have got with the basic code:

```
def search_columns_multi_val(column, values):
    searchlist = [] # the list storing the entered values
    for value in searchlist:
        print(value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python we can use *args and **kwargs for passing infinite number of unknown params.
Here is how you would use it in your code example:

```
def search_columns_multi_val(column, *args):
    searchlist = [] # the list storing the entered values
    for value in args:
         searchlist.append(value)
    print(searchlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
def f(column_name, *values):
    for value in values:
        print(value)
```

`values` is a tuple (not a list). If you really need a list, all you need to do is `values = list(values)`.

Here is how you can use it:

```
>>> f('name', 3, 5, 7, 9)
3
5
7
9
```

Answer (score 0):

you looking for this?

```
def Sum(*args): 
    totalSum = 0
    for number in args: 
        totalSum += number 
    print(totalSum) 
  
# function call 
Sum(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```